# HTML5 data Attribute formatting

Tags: javascript, json, html, attributes

I'm setting up a plugin and running into a weird issue...

I'm passing in settings like so:

```
data-plugin='{"setting1":false,"setting2":true,"setting3":false}'
```

This works fine, but would like to have the following, more user-friendly format:

```
data-plugin='{
    "setting1":false,
    "setting2":true,
    "setting3":false
    }'
```

However, when a return or space is placed inside, the settings no longer take effect. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong ....

Comment: What does your parsing code for that attribute look like?

Comment: I changed the examples so it did not look like you were setting the same thing.

Comment: What is the surrounding context?  In other words, are you writing pure HTML, or is it PHP or something else?  What does the HTML look like when you do a "view source" from the browser?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ebqjB/. After the edit: http://jsfiddle.net/ebqjB/1/

Comment: I'm simply pulling this with .data in jQuery, do I need to parse it?

Comment: @Aaron Nope, that should work as is: http://jsfiddle.net/ebqjB/2/

Comment: Awesome, as soon as I changed it from .data to .attr it worked fine :)

Comment: @Aaron That doesn't make sense, it should still work with `.data`. Just to satisfy my curiosity, could you please post the code you were using? (both html and jQuery)